# Node memory usage with HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

Can someone explain why the code below causes node's memory usage to blow up and never recover?

I understand why it would cause memory usage to shoot up, but it never comes back down.

I'm doing things I don't think should be necessary (setting variables to `null`) in an effort to cause garbage collection, but it doesn't make a difference.

I've also tried using `--expose-gc` and `global.gc()`, but it doesn't help.

Am I missing a reference here somewhere, or is there a bigger issue?

```
var https = require("https")

var i = 0;
while(i < 200) {

  var req = https.request({
    host: 'host.com',
    path: '/endpoint',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
        'Authorization': 'Basic abc123'
    }
  }, function(res) { res.resume(); res=null; });
  req.data = "a,b,c";
  req.write(req.data);
  req.end();
  req = null;
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node GC is "lazy" it tends to keep memory in his "old space" until it reach and hard limit (around 1.4/1.5Gb on 64bit env).
In our case (lot's of http requests) memory was getting higher and higher until it reach that threshold, and then was abrutly back to 200Mb.

You can use `--trace-gc` and `--trace-gc-verbose` to look at what kind of memory is used. You can set `--max-old-space-size` to force node to have a smaller limit than 1.4Gb, and thus trigger GC more frequently (it can impact perf, a full GC is synchronous and freeze the thread).